# panel.rect and log scale in trellis plot

Tags: r, lattice

I'm wondering about how to draw a highlighted rectangle with log y-axis in a trellis plot. My idea was to use panel.rect(), which works without a log scale:

```
set.seed(1)
y <- runif(100, min=1, max=1000)
x <- seq_along(y)

xyplot(y ~ x,
       panel=function(x,y,...) {
           cpl <- current.panel.limits()
           panel.rect(xleft=cpl$xlim[1], ybottom=10,
                      xright=cpl$xlim[2], ytop=500,
                      fill="lightgray", border="lightgray", alpha=.6)
           panel.xyplot(x,y,...)
           
       },
       scales=list(y=list(log=FALSE))
       )
```

However, when log=TRUE, the rectangle disappears. Are there any ideas? Thanks, Sven

Answer (score 0):

ok, this do the trick, first transform the y-coordinates for panel.rect():

```
xyplot(y ~ x, 
       panel=function(x,y, ...) {
           cpl <- current.panel.limits()
           yseq <- log(c(100,1000))
           panel.rect(xleft=cpl$xlim[1],
                      ybottom=yseq[1],
                      xright=cpl$xlim[2],
                      ytop=yseq[2],
                      fill="lightgray", border="lightgray", alpha=.6)
           panel.xyplot(x,y,...)
       },
       scales=list(y=list(log=2))
       )
```